# Get nested list from json

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, nested-lists

```
    [System.Serializable]
public class JsonObjects
{    
    public List<Levels> levels;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Levels
{
    public List<string> level_data;
}
```

deserialization:

```
objects = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonObjects>(jsonFile.text);
        List<Levels> levels = objects.levels;
```

How to make level_data accesible? I want to go through level data list and get the coordinates into vector2

Comment: well e.g. `levels[0].level_data` ? If those are coordinates though why not rather actually store them as such and use numeric values instead of strings?

Answer (score 0):

level_data list is situated in the levels list

```
List<string> levelData0=  levels[0].level_data; //    [ "50", "50", "950"...
List<string> levelData1=  levels[1].level_data;   //  [ "500", "80", "652",...
```